# Azure Data Factory how to convert csv to pdf?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to convert csv files into pdf using Azure Data Factory or any other Azure technology?

Comment: I imagine you are opening your CSV in excel and seeing a tabular format, and that is the format you want to see in PDF? No you can't do this directly in ADF. You basically need to find a library that does it for you, then write a script that calls that library, then run that script in something, probably Azure Functions or (my preference) Azure Automation.

Comment: You could also call a service that provides an API like this https://cloudconvert.com/csv-to-pdf - why don't you try that and see if it gives expected results. Alternatively, what is your coding experience level and preferred language? Where will the CSV be stored? locally or in blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting CSV (or any other file type) to PDF is not supported in **Azure data factory**.

You can use [Azure Logic apps](https://cloudmersive.com/examples/convert-csv-to-json-in-power-automate) or Azure functions and [Microsoft Graph to convert a file to PDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

> **Note**: You can call an API or execute azure functions in azure data factory pipeline.